# Make Apache call a script to test for authentication?

Tags: apache-http-server, authentication

I want to limit access to certain directories served by Apache.  I want the client to have to type a username and password, but then I want Apache to take the username and password that the person typed and pass them as arguments to a python script that I wrote to do the authentication.  Then, based on the output of said script, I want Apache to either allow or deny access.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this is using [`mod_auth_external`](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) or `mod_python`. The first allows you to implement custom authentication systems; the latter gives Apache an embedded Python interpreter, which can be used to [write a custom authentication script](http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/25). Neither are standard, or very popular, modules.

### However...

the easiest would be to simply have your authentication system update the password list that Apache uses. Apache comes with all the tools you need to add/update/delete users from either an .htpasswd or .htdigest file (it should be trivial to hook the `htpasswd` or `htdigest` commands into any user management system).

*Or*, you can have `mod_auth` (Apache's default authentication system) read from a database via the following modules:

- [`mod_auth_dbm`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_dbm.html) - a standard module that allows you to use the [dbm family of pre-relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm)
- [`mod_auth_mysql`](http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/) - a third-party module that allows you to use MySQL databases
- You may also be able to use PostgreSQL and other SQL databases by using [`mod_dbd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dbd.html) and [`mod_authn_dbd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html).

I would personally go this route, as it's more elegant than duplicating your user password hashes (hopefully you're not storing the passwords themselves) in a separate text file, and creating a new authentication system seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: mod_auth_external was exactly what I wanted.  Thank you!

Comment: if I have a separate authentication server (OAuth Bearer Token Issuer and Authenticator), then I guess I should go with mod_auth_external. Please correct me if I am wrong here. thanks

Comment: @FoyzulKarim Out of the options in the answer, yes. But I would first look into https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc to see if that'll better fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .htaccess to limit access to certain directories.

http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

You need to create a htpasswd file which you refer to from the .htaccess file

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Python: there seems to be a library that can handle htpasswd files:

http://pacopablo.com/wiki/pacopablo/blog/htpasswd-with-python

More about python and htpasswd:

http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.apache.html

I'm not familiar with python, and I can't give you a complete solution. I think however that it's possible, and probably not too complicated if you're familiar with python, with a bit of googling.